# Windows 7 64-bit PDF thumbnails problem

Tags: windows-7, pdf, thumbnails, preview

I cannot see thumbnails of PDF files on Windows 7 **64-bit**. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: May 2014 Acrobat Reader Update and this problem is still not fixed.

Comment: This should be reported so Adobe fixes this, here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform

Comment: This really worked for me. http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/

Comment: No longer supported with Acrobat Reader DC. Need to use another reader.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open Adobe Reader.
2. Choose File > Open, and browse to the folder containing your PDFs.
3. Switch the file view to show icons. This causes Adobe Reader to load (and cache) thumbnails for the files in this folder. If necessary, scroll up and down to make sure all the thumbnails have loaded.
4. Click Cancel, and close Adobe Reader.
5. Refresh that folder in Windows Explorer, and bask in the sweet thumbnaily goodness.

Annoying if you have a lot of folders, but effective :)

Comment: This is not the best solution. You have to do this every time you want to see the thumbnails.

Comment: This does nothing for my installation.  Viewing thumbnails from either Adobe Reader or Acrobat produces no images.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Adobe haven't made available a 64-bit version of their ifilter, which Windows 7 needs to index pdf's and make thumbnails. However, Foxit PDF viewer has a 64-bit ifilter, but I'm unsure if it will also make thumbnails.

Comment: http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/PDF_iFilter_8_-_64-bit_Support this links contains adobe's 64-bit ifilter. I am installing now, I will write the result soon. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Comment: It's still in beta isn't it? The Foxit pdf ifilter has received some recognition as it's apparently being used in Microsoft's own hosted services! Look here for the free (desktop) download: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/
I'm installing that now, will let you know how it goes..

Comment: I installed this Foxit PDF IFilter in Windows 7 x64 and it still does not generate thumbnails for PDFs in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF XCHANGE works perfectly - http://www.docu-track.com/download/PDFXVwer.zip

Comment: It produces thumbnails in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895561), another option is to run a copy of windows explorer in 32-bit mode.  Then Adobe's 32-bit previewer will kick in.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) (606.0722_enu_Setup.exe - 29MB) will save this problem for me .it is free and really pretty and really worth seeing and testing this solution

Answer (score 0):

I use an old version of the full application (Acrobat 9.5.5) as well as Adobe Reader.  I had Acrobat set as the default application, as I'd prefer.  I read [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/949406) that setting Adobe Reader as the default will fix the problem.  Required a reboot as prompted and then worked for me like a charm.